# Organising webparts in visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

Quick question. When creating web parts in vs2010, is it best to group all web parts into one project or create separate projects.  I cant quite get my head round how best to organise this.  The web parts will be part of a bigger Intranet solution but will be completely separate entities that will be developed and updated independently from each other over a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick question, not so quick answer. It indeed depends on the structure of your intranet and how you want to make it available. 
Here are a few thinks that are important to consider.

- Are a lot of the webparts going to share code (ex. I can imagine logging will be shared)? Ok you can put the
  shared code in a separate project, but if you are going to reuse a
  lot it can be handy to have everything in the same solution. If you are sure that you want them separate, you can go with the wsp for each webpart solution. But consider that you will also have a separate feature for each webpart.
- Where are your webparts being used? If you have a few webapplications and only certain webparts are going to be used in a certain webapplication. Then you can consider putting those webparts in a separate package.
- Hand in hand with the previous topic, do you always want to make every webpart available? If you work with one webapplication, with different sitecollections it is possible that you don't always want to so all the webparts. To solve this you can consider putting the webparts under different features and only activating the feature of the webparts that you want.

I am sure there are some more, but these are the ones that come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

actually its depends on your requirement. but its fine if wrap all in the single as only webpart executes which we adds on the page. so its not going to affect any performance issue or anything else.